# error create mfc new project vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I got this problem when i started to create new mfc project. I got blank dialog, after choose mfc template for project. I tried another project using c#, there's no problem, but when it is going to create new project using c++, the blank problem appear. Had anyone else have this problem?

Comment: What error? What _exactly_ happens?

Comment: C++ and C# projects are completely unrelated. They uses different build systems, project templates, etc. I don't know why you bring up C# project creation, which is unrelated to your question.